# Export data from mathematica script

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I am writing a mathematica script and running it in the linux batch shell. The script gives as a result a list of numbers. I would like to write this list to a file as a one single column without the braces and commas. For this, I tried to use Export comand as

```
Export["file.txt", A1, "Table"]
```

but I get the error:

> Export::infer: Cannot infer format of file test1.txt

I tried with other format but i got the same error.
Could someone please tell what is wrong and what i can do? Thank beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
A1 = {1,2,3};
Export["test.tab", Transpose[{A1}], "Table"];
```

produces a single column without braces and commas.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to export the file in TABLE, why don't you try something like this ,

```
Export["file.txt", A1, "Text"]
```